# Node.js Railway with sass/stylus/less

Tags: node.js, express, railway.js

i started using [**railway**](http://railwayjs.com/) (a node.js mvc framework) and i want to use sass/less/stylus as a css render engin. 
i couldn't find how to configure that in railway.
railway uses [express.js](http://expressjs.com/guide) so i guess i can install it via that.
i already installed stylus (and all the rest) via `npm install stylus`.
i also uses `stylesheet_link_tag` to link to my css files.
any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use https://github.com/emberfeather/less.js-middleware.
its give u what u need

Answer (score 1):

after some research and thanks to my friend @sivan here, i found the answer.
the steps to integrate css rendering engin are (i'll demonstrate with [stylus](http://learnboost.github.com/stylus/), but the rest are similar):
install stylus

```
npm install stylus
```

npmfile.js

```
require('stylus');
```

environment.js

```
var stylus = require('stylus');
app.configure(function(){
var cwd = process.cwd(); //your root directory

app.use(stylus.middleware({
    src: __dirname + '/public', //your *.styl files here
    compress: true
}));

app.use(express.static(cwd + '/public', {maxAge: 86400000}));
...
}
```

then create a file ending with `.styl` extension. for example: public/stylsheets/style1.styl

```
#div2
  color blue //your css here
```

and simply link to this generated .css file from your html page

```
<%- stylesheet_link_tag('style1') %>
```

more about stylus middleware [here](https://github.com/LearnBoost/stylus/blob/master/docs/middleware.md).
hope it will save time to whoever will get into the same issue.